# On bounding the eigenvalue of a sum of a symmetric matrix and a bounded matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ symmetric matrix with eigenvalues bounded between $\ell \in \mathbb{R}$ and $L \in \mathbb{R}$, that is $ \ell <\lambda_i < L$  for $i \in \{ 1, \dots , n \}$ where $ \lambda_i$ represent the eigenvalues of $A$ and $\ell < L$.

Let  $B$ be a $n \times n$ generic matrix such that $\| B \| < M \in \mathbb{R}$  (alternatively let $B$ have each element $b_{ij} < M$).

then I would like to say that  the eigenvalues of $B - A $ are bounded between $\ell - M$ and $L + M$, is this true?

EDIT: As pointed out in a comment as stated $B - A $ could have complex eigenvalues, so to keep the question relevant assume $B$ also symmetric.

Comment: If $B$ isn't symmetric, then the eigenvalues of $B-A$ might not be real, so you might have to either require $B$ to be symmetric or change the "bounded between $\ell-M$ and $L+M$" part.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 Thank you! edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say they are bounded between $-L-M$ and $M-\ell$ in the case of symmetric $B$. It is well known that for symmetric $A$ and $B$
$$ \lambda_\max(A+B) \leq \lambda_\max(A) + \lambda_\max(B) $$
holds. This means
$$\begin{align}
\lambda_\max((-A)+(-B)) &\leq \lambda_\max(-A) + \lambda_\max(-B) \\
-\lambda_\min(A+B) &\leq -\lambda_\min(A) - \lambda_\min(B) \\
\lambda_\min(A+B) &\geq \lambda_\min(A) + \lambda_\min(B)
\end{align}$$
Hence,
$$
-L-M \leq \lambda_\min(-A) + \lambda_\min(B) \leq \lambda_i(B-A) \leq \lambda_\max(-A) + \lambda_\max(B) \leq M-\ell
$$